# jQuery-File-Upload: Handle server errors

Tags: error-handling, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

I'm trying to implement error handling for blueimp's jQuery-File-Upload. It's easy to implement for errors which i can catch on the server an wrap it into a JSON-object. But what if the server has a PHP-error and the message is displayed as standard-PHP-message? I tried to handle it with the fail-callback:

```
jQuery('#fileupload').fileupload({
    fail: function (ev, data) {
        if (data.jqXHR) {
            alert('Server-error:\n\n' + data.jqXHR.responseText); 
        }
    }, 
    otherOptions
});
```

It's working, but the callback is also fired if I press the cancel-button to remove an image. So I added the if with the data.jqXHR to differ between a server error and a cancel-button-press. But then, if cancel-button is pressed, image isn't removed from the list anymore.

Any idea's how to implement such an error handling for unexpected server errors?

Thanks, Ben

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer. I needed to use

```
.bind('fileuploadfail', function (e, data) {
```

instead of overwriting the fail-function directly.

Comment: or .on('fileuploadfail', function (e, data) {

Comment: This will also be fired if cancel button press.

Answer (score 1):

The answer provided by the asker did not work for me. I used a variable to indicate whether the failure was triggered by the user or not.

```
add: function (e, data) {
        if (data.autoUpload || (data.autoUpload !== false && $(this).fileupload('option', 'autoUpload'))) {
            $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
                // UPLOAD INDICATOR
                // file heading
                single_upload = "<b class='file_upload'>"+file.name+"</b>";
                // cancel btn
                single_upload += "<a class='remove_upload'> || Cancel!</a>";
                // contain
                single_upload = "<div class='upload'>"+single_upload+"</div>";
                // create and display node related to specific upload
                data.context = $(single_upload).appendTo(document.body);

                // CANCEL BTN LISTENER
                $(data.context).find(".remove_upload").click(function() {
                    // prevent displaying of server error
                    // (prevent fileupload "fail" event trigger)
                    fileupload_userCancelledUpload = true;
                    jqXHR.abort();
                    data.context.remove();
                })
            });
            var jqXHR;
            data.process().done(function () {
                jqXHR = data.submit();
            });
        }
    },

fail: function (e, data) {
        if (!fileupload_userCancelledUpload) {
            // catches server errors (not validation errors), such as 413
            handleUploadFailure(data.context, " Server error: "+$(data.jqXHR.responseText).filter("title").text());
        }
        fileupload_userCancelledUpload = false;
    }
```